# Android Tensorflow Lite(nightly), convert [H,W,C] -> [B,C,H,W] in Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

'm able to generate proper output in python/cpp using TFlite[v2.6].

```
// [H,W,C] -> [B,C,H,W]
input_tensor = input_tensor.permute({2, 0, 1}).unsqueeze(0);
```

However in Android, 'm unable to do so.Tensor's shape is in [H, W, C] format.
Could someone please point me to documentation for these conversions[transpose/permute/squeeze/unsqueeze] for Android.